# css3 tranform changing relative element of absolute children

Tags: css, transform, css-position

I'm finding that setting a transform (rotate, skew, translateX, etc) on an element that is the parent of a child that is absolutely positioned makes the parent act as the new "position:relative" to the child. I have sample code here:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/tjrnN/[1](http://jsfiddle.net/tjrnN/)

My question is if this is normal, i.e. setting the transform is supposed to establish a new coordinate system for the absolutely positioned children?

If so, is there a way to specify that the child element should not be included in the parent's transform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If so, is there a way to specify that the child element should not be included in the parent's transform?

Move it out of the animated element?